# How to solve this mathematical equation for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I am trying to solve this equation for $x$:
$$
y = 1 - e^\left( \frac{{ x ^ {0.22} }  ({e^{-cx^{0.22}}-1)}}{c} \right)
$$
I tried by transferring 1 to left hand side and then taking ln on both sides but that doesn't gives me the solution for x

Can anyone help ?

Comment: $$\text{You wrote :}\quad y = 1 - e^{[ { x ^ {0.22} }  { \exp ( - c x^{0.22}) - 1 } / c ]}$$

There is an ambiguity in your LATEX edition. Do you mean 

$$y = 1 - e^{ { x ^ {0.22} }   \exp ( - c x^{0.22}) - \frac{1}{c} }$$
or
$$y = 1 - e^{ { x ^ {0.22} } \left( \frac{ \exp ( - c x^{0.22}) - 1  }{c}\right)}$$
or
$$y = 1 - e^{   \frac{ { \big(x ^ {0.22} }\exp ( - c x^{0.22})\big) - 1 }{c}}$$
or something else ? All these equations have different solutions.

Comment: Latter you corrected it as : $$y = 1 - e^{[ \frac{{ x ^ {0.22} }  {e^{(-cx^{0.22}-1})}}{c} ]}$$ There is still a mismatch in parenthesis. Your equation can be understood on two different manners. Please, correct it.

Comment: @JJacquelin Now it's all right please help me how can i solve it.

Comment: You can express $-cx^{0.22}e^{-cx^{0.22}}$ in terms of $c$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was important to be precise about the parenthesis because the slightest change is likely to make the equation solvable or not solvable analytically.

For example the quation $(1)$ is solvable thanks to a special function
$$\boxed{y = 1 - e^ \frac{({ x ^ {0.22} }  {e^{-cx^{0.22}}})-1}{c} }\tag 1$$
$\frac{({ x ^ {0.22} }  {e^{-cx^{0.22}}})-1}{c}=\ln|1-y|$

$ x ^ {0.22} e^{-cx^{0.22}}=1+c\ln|1-y|$

$ (-cx ^ {0.22}) e^{(-cx^{0.22})}=-c-c^2\ln|1-y|$

With $\begin{cases}X=(-cx ^ {0.22}) \\ Y=-c-c^2\ln|1-y| \end{cases}$ the equation is transformed into $\quad Xe^X=Y$

The solution is $\quad X=W(Y)$ .

$W$ is the Lambert W function : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

$-cx ^ {0.22}=W\left(-c-c^2\ln|1-y| \right)$

$$x=\left(-\frac{1}{c}W\left(-c-c^2\ln|1-y| \right)\right)^{1/0.22}$$

This is not the same for equation $(2)$ :

$$\boxed{y = 1 - e^ \frac{{ x ^ {0.22} }  ({e^{-cx^{0.22}}-1)}}{c} }\tag 2$$

$\frac{{ x ^ {0.22} }  ({e^{-cx^{0.22}}-1)}}{c}=\ln|1-y|$

With $\begin{cases}X=(-cx ^ {0.22}) \\ Y=-c^2\ln|1-y| \end{cases}$ the equation is transformed into $\quad Xe^X-X=Y$

This is not the Lambert equation $Xe^X=Y$. The Lambert W function is no longer convenient.

A different special function would be necessary. As far as I know, up to now, no convenient special function has been standardized for solving this kind of equation.

Do not expect an explicit solution for equation $(2)$. One have to solve it approximately with numerical calculus. They are a lot of numerical methods, for example Newton-Raphson, etc. But the parameters $c$ and $y$ have to be known on numerical form.

Comment: the equation which you considerd in part 2 is the actual equation which i want to solve and Yes the parameters y and c are known y = 0.2343 and c = 1.875

Comment: Can You tell me how will i proceed with Newton-Raphson for solution of x?

Comment: I will not write a textbook on a forum. One can find it in many course books and on the net. For example : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html . For equation $(2)$ a numerical solution with y=0.2343 and c=1.875 is x=0.184895539271928

Comment: Hi Jean ! $ Xe^X-X=Y$ can write $e^{-X}=\frac X{X+Y}$ and the solution is given in terms of the generalized Lambert function. This being said, ????. Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi Claude ! You are right, one can find in the literature different attempts of generalization of the Lambert W function. But they are not standardized such as the usual one is. I will not go on this slippery slope. By the way I was expecting your answer about a numerical method. In fact the OP should probably more interested by  numerical  than analytical solving. Cheers.

Comment: I missed your message. Don't forget to start with *@username* except if it is a comment to my own answer. By the way, Fred called me yesterday. Nice guy ! We spent a lot of time speaking about **La** method. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t = \frac{x^{0.22}e^{-cx^{0.22}}}{c}$.

Then, $-cx^{0.22}e^{-cx^{0.22}} = -c^2t$.

$-cx^{0.22} = W(-c^2t)$, where $W(x)$ is the [Lambert's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which is defined as an inverse to the function $f(w) = we^w$.

Now, we have

$x^{0.22} = -\frac{1}{c}W(-c^2t).$

$x^{\frac{11}{50}} = -\frac{1}{c}W(-c^2t).$

$x = \left(-\frac{1}{c}W(-c^2t)\right)^{\frac{50}{11}}.$

Let us define $t$:

$y = 1-e^t \Leftrightarrow t = \log{(1-y)} \Rightarrow$

$x = \left(-\frac{1}{c}W(-c^2\log(1-y))\right)^{\frac{50}{11}}.$

Comment: Please review the question that 'c' is in complete divide that is not 1/c

Comment: Sorry Earlier it was not written clearly.

Comment: This different from [WolframAlpha's answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y+%3D+1+-+e%5E%28%28x%5Ea+e%5E%28-cx%5Ea-1%29%29%2Fc%29+for+x+).